# If f is a continuous function that's differentiable show that there exists $d∈(a,b)$ such that $f′(d)=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

Hi all i'm struggling on this question and I don't know how to do it.

Let $f : [a, b] → R$ be a continuous function that is differentiable on $(a, b)$.

We assume that $f(a) < f(p)$ and $f(p) > f(b)$ for some $p ∈ (a, b)$. Show that there exists
$d ∈ (a, b)$ such that $f
'
(d) = 0.$

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it be Rolle's theorem if it was $f(a)<f(p)<f(b)$?

Comment: I would think you'd have to use the Mean Value Theorem with some  tricky function like $g(x) = f(x)-f(p)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the value of $f$ at $p$ is more than its values at endpoints and hence it follows that $f$ attains its maximum value at an interior point of interval $[a, b]$ and since $f$ is differentiable the derivative $f'$ vanishes at point of maxima.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases to consider:

- $f(a)<f(b)<f(p)$. Then by the intermediate value theorem, there exists $c \in (a,p)$ such that $f(c)=f(b)$. Now apply Rolle's Theorem.
- $f(b)<f(a)<f(p)$. Then by the intermediate value theorem, there exists $c \in (p,b)$ such that $f(c)=f(a)$. Now apply Rolle's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose that $f(a) < f(b)$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is an $a'$ between $a$ and $p$ such that $f(a') = f(b)$.  Now, apply Rolle's theorem on the interval $(a',b)$.